# Smooth animation of box shadows in input

Tags: css, animation, smoothing

i need to create "pulse" animation of box shadow. I know trick with :after, but it not works with input because it's self closing element.
Here's example of my code. If possible I would like to solve it in css/less and try to not use js.
I forgot to add that i have some structure from package and I can't change it.
Structure is like
*"form > div > input"*. And i need to add that animation if input is focused.

```css
.elem {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
  line-heiht: 50px;
  font-size: 42px;
}

@keyframes pulseGreenShadow {
  from {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px green
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px green
  }
}

.elem:focus {
  animation: pulseGreenShadow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse;
}
```

```html
<input class="elem">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SkylinR/cowzb1hg/227/

Than you in advance for any help

Comment: Your example works for me, what's the issue?

Comment: It grows step by step, shakes or something like that, not smoothly pulse. My clients don't like it. :( (Browser Chrome)

Comment: Is it ok for you to use contentEditable `div`s?

Comment: No because that input comes from package and I can't change those html. More over there is structure and i can't add div inside form. (I thought about way to add div after input and use input:focus + div, and add div position absolute etc. but in this case i can't do that)
I'm afraid that it's not possible with css, but maybe in less someone know the solution.

Comment: Animating box shadow will come with performance issues. So I would recommend to wrap input with a div and use after psuedo element for animation

Comment: Good point, but i can't add anything inside form, I can wrap form but this is not the solution because then i will not be able to detect focus on input.

Comment: If you are worrying about div taking a whole row in a form you could use `display: inline-block`. Moreover you can possibly put the inputs into divs or transform inputs into divs on the fly.

Comment: Pseudo element won't help in this case. You have to increase difference between this two shadows.

Comment: Richard it's not about wraping form because it's not a problem (in form i have only input), but how to detect focus on input then?
Makshh what You mean by increasing difference? I've changed size of shadow 10 times but still the same. also i've trying to manipulate with time of animation but also it's not working.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqPPgb

Comment: Here's kind of a hack: use a animated border image. Apply it when focused.

Comment: makshh thanks for help ! :D that codepen works fine

Answer (score 4):

See if this is any better for you:

```css
input {
 border: 1px solid lightgray;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 width: 200px;
}

input:focus {
 animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
 outline: none;
}


@keyframes glow {
    0% {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.2);
    } 
    100% {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,255,0,.8);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Great it's what i've needed :) Thanks (isn't that the same solution as makshh  send?)

Comment: A lot in common which is to be expected. Difference is in the detail ;)